# Wordpress template for multiple custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple wordpress template files:

- single-example_1.php
- single-example_2.php
- archiv-example_1.php
- archiv-example_2.php

These are the exactly the same, they are just targeting different *custom post types*. Because of this I want to combine them into one. I have added this function:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) 
{
    $my_types = array( 'example_1', 'example_2' );
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $my_types ) )
            return $template;
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-example.php'; 
});
```

This "redirects" every single- und archiv- sites to the same template.

**How can I redirect the archive pages only to archiv-example and single pages to single-example?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this - you will need to handle the template for both the archive templates as well as the single post templates.

For archives use the [`is_post_type_archive($post_types)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) function to check and see if the current request is for an archive page of one of the post types you want to return. If it's a match, return your common archive template.

For single posts use the [`is_singular($post_types)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) function to see if the current request is for a single post of one of the post types you specify. If it's a match, return the common single post template.

In both cases you'll want to return the `$template` if it isn't a match in case it was modified by another filter.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    // your custom post types
    $my_types = array( 'example_1', 'example_2' );

    // is the current request for an archive page of one of your post types?
    if ( is_post_type_archive(  $my_types ) ){
        // if it is return the common archive template
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/archive-example.php';
    } else 
    // is the current request for a single page of one of your post types?
    if ( is_singular( $my_types ) ){
        // if it is return the common single template
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-example.php';
    } else {
        // if not a match, return the $template that was passed in
        return $template;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great explained!

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting to use `is_post_type_archive($post_type)` to check if the query is being served for an archive page or not.

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( $post_type ) ) 
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/archive-example.php';
return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-example.php';
```

Comment: For the OP: you can pass an array of post types to the [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) function.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. How can I add a filter for the post types? (as I have done using `$my_types = array( 'example_1', 'example_2' );`? I am not able to achieve this one on my own, it would be great if you can help me out another time!

Comment: You code assumes there are no other post types, this would break if there was an `example_3` that had a different template.

Comment: @doublesharp yep you're not wrong. you can just pass an array to the function `is_post_type_archive($my_type)` using the `$my_type` variable currently declared, oh you've already posted that. yep, +1